# Matplotlib ArtistAnimation turns up blank

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I am trying to convert a torch tensor into a gif in a jupyter notebook. I use the following code to do that:

```
    import imageio
    fig = plt.figure()

    images = []
    for image in tensors[0]:
        images.append(np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1,2,0)))
    imageio.mimsave('./movie.gif', images)
    ani = ArtistAnimation(fig, images,interval=200)
    plt.show()
```

but for some reason the output of plt.show() is just a blank video. I have put

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

at the top of my script and the movie.gif that I save is correct. The shape of my data is also correct. [image]

Here is a picture of my output.
Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have similar data in my environment, so I haven't been able to verify this, but there are several ways to make a GIF image from an animation created with the 'ArtistAnimation' function, but the easiest is to save it using the PIL library.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import imageio

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

images = []

for image in tensors[0]:
    # images.append(np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1, 2, 0)))
    images.append([plt.imshow(np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1, 2, 0)))])
anim = ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=1000, repeat=False)
anim.save('./movie.gif', writer='pillow')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can already save the gif. My problem is that when I do plt.show() it shows the empty figure like I showed above. I tried this code but it still doesn't show anything.

Comment: Does `plt.imshow(image)` show the image? Can you provide toy data to the extent possible?

Comment: Yes plt.imshow(image) does show the image. The data has a shape of `torch.Size([32, 10, 3, 128, 128])`. But when I index it and tranpose it the shape changes to `(128,128,3)` with the list len of 10.

Comment: I'd like to check again, does `plt.imshow(np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1, 2, 0)))` show the image?

Comment: Yes it does. It shows the image correctly.

Comment: This is the last one. I'll rewrite the code and you can run it. Make the image object a list.

Comment: Last but not least, `np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1, 2, 0))` is a list, right? imeges is just a multiple list, so `plt.imshow(np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1, 2, 0)))` with You may need to do this.

Comment: Am I supposed to put that in the append call like this `images.append(plt.imshow(np.transpose(image.numpy(), (1, 2, 0))))`? Or somewhere else? Because doing it like that just shows one image.

Comment: Did you see the image? That's a step in the right direction. I've updated the code, so please try running it.